# Sockets in ArrayList wont get closed

Tags: java, sockets, arraylist

So i have this application in which I am storing Sockets in an ArrayList on the Server side. When the client closes its application the socket must close as well but It doesnt reflect the changes in the ArrayList in the server.

```
class arrays
{
    public static ArrayList<Socket> online_buyer=new ArrayList<Socket>(); 
    public static ArrayList<Socket> online_seller=new ArrayList<Socket>(); 
        public static ArrayList<String> buyer_prod=new ArrayList<String>();

}

    public void seller_display()
    {
        while(true)
        {   


            if(flag==1)
            {

                synchronized(sock)
                {
                for(int i=0;i<arrays.online_buyer.size();i++)
                {
                System.out.println(arrays.buyer_prod.get(i));
                }
                flag=0;
                }
            }


            check2();

        }

    }


    public void check2()
    {
        for(int i=0;i<arrays.online_buyer.size();i++)
        {
            try 
            {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            } 
            catch (InterruptedException e) 
            {
            e.printStackTrace();
            }
            **while(!arrays.online_buyer.get(i).isConnected())** 
            {
                arrays.online_buyer.remove(i);
                arrays.buyer_user.remove(i);
                arrays.buyer_add.remove(i);
                arrays.buyer_prod.remove(i);
                arrays.time.remove(i);
                arrays.buyer_no.remove(i);
                flag=1;
                System.out.println("RECORD DELETED");
            }


        }

    }


public void run()
    {
    get_details();

    }
}
```

Now the statement **while(!arrays.online_buyer.get(i).isConnected())**  must be while(!false)=true. When i close the socket from the client side as isconnected()method must return false. But this statement never runs to be false even if i close the socket from client.

Comment: Ever tried to compile this code? :)

Comment: TCP to the rescue! The server can't detect a closed connection unless it is trying to read or write to it.

Comment: Can your question be boiled down to "why does `socket.isConnected()` return `true` even after the client closed the connection"?

Comment: As far as I remember you will not notice a client close event in the `isConnected` state but by an EOF signal in the input stream.

Comment: @rmuller : This is just a part of code. The whole code was pretty huge. It compiles fine

Comment: @ThomasJungblut : So the isconnected() connection is Useless?

Comment: @user3686725 AFAIK the isconnected turns to false when the *server* closes the connection.

Comment: @chiccodoro It returns `false` when the *local application* closes the *socket.* It has nothing to do with the state of the *connection* whatsoever. Whether the 'local application' is the server or the client has nothing to do with it.

Answer (score 1):

> When I close the socket from the client side as `isConnected()` method must return false.

No it mustn't. Where does it say that?

The reality of this is that `isConnected()` returns true if you have ever connected this `Socket,` which you have. The correct way to detect *peer* termination is as follows:

- `read()` returns -1
- `readLine()` returns `null`
- `readXXX()` throws `EOFException` for any other *XXX*
- `write()` throws `IOException`

Comment: Thanks man. They should have named the method was everconnected

Comment: 'Returns the connection state *of the socket*' is clear enough, but I would agree they should have added warnings about *not of the connection* to both this and `isClosed().`